# Looking for the title of a horror movie

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I am looking for the title of this horror movie that I saw when I was a kid. I am pretty sure that the movie is not later than 2005.

What I can remember:

1. The story is about a man who had an affair with a student.
2. They met on a rainy day. While riding his car, he saw the girl soaking wet and helped her.
3. The girl disappeared. The wife found out about the affair and accidentally killed the girl. The wife hid the body inside the wall of a new room that they were constructing. I think it was their child's room.
4. The child was diagnosed as having an "Elektra Syndrome" because she is too attached to her father while her mother receives animosity. The child is in fact, being possessed by the girl.
5. At the ending, someone discovered the corpse and the girl somewhat "resurrected" and took her revenge on the wife.

Comment: Did you check IMDB and look up the actor's name?

Answer (score 3):

This almost sounds like the plot of the South Korean movie [Phone](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Phone_(film)) from 2002.

> When Ho-jung's daughter Young-ju answers an anonymous phone call on Ji-won's new cell phone, the girl screams and begins to show a disturbing attraction for her father and jealous rejection towards her mother. 
>   [...]
>   Ji-won also discovers that Jin-hee's dead body was hidden inside one of the walls at the house she is staying at

Here is the trailer:

Answer (score 0):

This one is later but seems pretty similar [Messages Deleted](http://imdb.com/rg/an_share/title/title/tt1072754/).
The actor is the same from Scooby doo.